# Is it possible to use Python based Unit Test frameworks and runners, to test C Code

Tags: python, c, unit-testing

Python based Unit test Frameworks like "nose" have a lot of rich features, i wonder if we can leverage them to test C Code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Of course you can.... but you'll have to write a binding to call your C code in python (with [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) for example), and write the tests in python (this is really possible and an easy way to do smart tests)

**Example :**

- Write a dummy C library.

*foolib.c*

```
int my_sum(int , int);

int my_sum(int a , int b);
{
    return a + b;
}
```

- Compile it as a shared library:

`gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,foolib -o foolib.so -fPIC foolib.c`

- Write the wrapper with ctypes:

*foolib_test.py*

```
import ctypes
import unittest

class FooLibTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.foolib = ctypes.CDLL('/full/path/to/foolib.so')

    def test_01a(self):
        """ Test in an easy way"""
        self.failUnlessEqual(4, foolib.my_sum(2, 2))
```

And then, when running this test with nose you should have a nice test of your C code :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate or give me an example, for me to get an idea of how complex this would be. Thanks

Comment: If this is simple C files, like the adder, or hello world, i believe this approach will work, what if this is legacy code and one file has many dependencies m also one module needs the other one , how will this work ?

Comment: @kamal : the most difficult part in case of complex code would be the makefile part :)

Comment: Two minor comments about the above example. One is that the `int my_sum(int a, int b)` should not have a semicolon after it the second time it is written, and also that `self.failUnlessEqual(4, self.foolib.my_sum(2,2))` (note the `self.failUnlessEqual`)